# Python compiled pattern match with flags, cp.search to match at beginning of line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this, which gives no match, why ?:

```
>>> p = r'abc'
>>> cp = re.compile(p, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> m = cp.search('ABC', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> m # NO MATCH # 1
```

But, this gives a match, why ?

```
>>> m = cp.search('  ABC', re.IGNORECASE) # introduced spaces, ABC no longer at the beginning 
>>> m # MATCH # 2
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1082b5ac0>
```

To get a match in #1 all I have to do is drop re.IGNORECASE, why so ?

```
>>> m = cp.search('ABC')
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10827e308>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (in the interpreter) you print out the help on cp.search:

```
help(cp.search)
```

you will see:

```
Help on built-in function search:
search(string=None, pos=0, endpos=9223372036854775807, *, pattern=None) method of _sre.SRE_Pattern instance
    Scan through string looking for a match, and return a corresponding match object instance.

    Return None if no position in the string matches.
```

Notice that this function does not take any flags, but what you were actually passing your flag to the 'pos' argument, which was why you got an unexpected result.

Comment: How'd you get `pos=0, endpos=9223372036854775807` in your method  help ? I don't see that. But what you said makes total sense. Thanks

Comment: @abc No idea, maybe we're running different versions of Python.

Comment: `$ python --version
Python 2.7.10`

Comment: @abc I was using Python 3.6